# tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: No-Header Value?

Tags: iphone, ios, header, tableview

In my tableview, i need the header only when something is typed in the search box. And no header in normal view. what should i return if i don need header?

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
UIView *section1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 22)];

if(tableView==ExpTableView)
{
    [section1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:241.0f/255.0f green:57.0f/255.0f blue:130.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 3, tableView.bounds.size.width - 10, 18)];

    if (isSearchOn)
    {

        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Search Results for '%@'", searchTextValue];
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [section1 addSubview:label];

        return section1;

    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}

return nil;
}
```

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: What happened when you tried it ?

Answer (score 0):

its the

```
if(tableView==ExpTableView)
```

that's breaking it. you're assuming it always is but it is not when you're searching. when searching it will never go in to that block

you should have two ifs. one is that one and one that checks to see if the table is the searchview

something like:

```
if(tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView])
```

so from my take on what you're trying to do:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if(tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView]) {

        UIView *section1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 22)];
        [section1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:241.0f/255.0f green:57.0f/255.0f blue:130.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 3, tableView.bounds.size.width - 10, 18)];

        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Search Results for '%@'", searchTextValue];
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [section1 addSubview:label];

        return section1;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

this method works hand in hand with the following method that you need to also alter so that you get the functionality that you're after:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(tableView == [[self searchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView])
        return /*DESIRED_HEIGHT_OF_HEADER*/;
    }else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to add `return nil;` as a last line otherwise it will show a warning.

Comment: i tried this.. even then, the default header is displayed when search is not made.. i don want any header in normal view.. header is req only during search..

Comment: @ManojEllappan it sounds like an issue with -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

Comment: you need to make sure you're setting that to 0 if you don't want the header. insert the same check in that method that i mentioned in my answer